# ЧПУ в фильтрах ссылками

Tags: ссылки, чпу, фильтрация

День добрый. Хочу на своем сайте сделать такую же структуру ссылок в фильтре, как тут: https://axeum.ru/category/zapchasti-dlja-apple-iphone
[image: подробнее]
Т.е. вроде как и фильтр (если нажать, то можно чз селектор выбрать несколько), но при этом и прямая ссылка.

Мб есть какой-то модуль на битре или посоветуете, как сделать самостоятельно? Хотя бы направление в которое копать.

Comment: Враньё! Первый раз, когда вы кликаете, то попадаете на обычную страницу бренда (да, типа фильтр), а когда выбираете несколько категорий, подключается обычная фильтрация (причем не самая лучшая)

Answer (score 0):

Так это же не фильтр, это просто система тегов. Создаёте таблицу тегов, у каждого тега есть id и ЧПУ адрес тут же в БД прописан. Каждый товар когда заносите в БД присваиваете ему один из тегов. Дальше всё просто, при клике на тег, открывается его страница и выбираются все товары у которых стоит этот тег.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую!